# Miranda To Haskell - What is the improved version?

Tags: haskell

I'm working out the code from [this](http://conal.net/papers/warren-burton/Functional%20Programming%20and%20Quadtrees.pdf) paper. It's bugging me that my translation is more verbose. It occurs to me I'm missing something obvious that would make it as succinct as the original Miranda.

Here's the Miranda:

```
fix :: qtree(*) -> qtree(*)
fix(Leaf(x)) = Leaf(x)
fix(Internal(nw, ne, sw, se)) =
   merge(Internal(fix(nw), fix(ne), fix(sw), fix(se)))
   where
      merge(Internal (Leaf(x), Leaf(x), Leaf(x), Leaf(x))) = Leaf(x)
      merge(other) = other
```

Notice the LHS of `merge`. It captures the case where all four leaves have the same value. Can't do a straight transliteration into Haskell, for I'll get a complaint of multiple definitions of `x`. Here's my version:

```
fix :: (Eq a) => QTree a -> QTree a
fix (Leaf a) = Leaf a
fix (Internal nw ne sw se) =
   merge (Internal (fix nw) (fix ne) (fix sw) (fix se))
      where
   merge internal@(Internal (Leaf w) (Leaf x) (Leaf y) (Leaf z))
     | (w == x) && (x == y) && (y == z) = Leaf x
     | otherwise                        = internal
   merge other = other
```

How can I get closer to what is going on in the Miranda code?

Comment: I guess you could write `allEq [] = True; allEq (x:xs) = all (x ==) xs` which might help you a little.  Ultimately non-linear patterns are not in Haskell and they are in Miranda, it appears, so you will have to do a little extra work to compensate.  Btw you can get rid of the `| otherwise` line altogether, the next equation will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks. I always put in an otherwise as a reflex. Good catch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For reference, a pattern with a repeated name like that is called **non-linear**. Miranda supports these and Haskell doesn't. It's a design trade-off taken by the *original* Haskell design comittee back in [1988](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pure-lang/IReQo-L8-Ik). [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pure-lang/IReQo-L8-Ik) has some additional rationale for not supporting non-linear patterns in Haskell.

Unfortunately, this means that you can't really get close to Miranda using Haskell's pattern matching. You'll have to write some code that explicitly compares values for equality, like you have.

The one improvement you *can* easily make is to get rid of your `othewise` case: if all the guards fail, pattern matching moves on to the next pattern. You could also make your equality check a bit shorter, but you **can't get rid of the check completely**. Here's a version that seems a bit improved to me:

```
fix :: (Eq a) => QTree a -> QTree a
fix (Leaf a) = Leaf a
fix (Internal nw ne sw se) =
  merge (Internal (fix nw) (fix ne) (fix sw) (fix se))
  where merge (Internal (Leaf w) (Leaf x) (Leaf y) (Leaf z))
          | all (== w) [x, y, z] = Leaf x
        merge other = other
```

Answer (score 6):

You might find that [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) or something like it works really well for your quadtree:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
import Data.Data(Data)
import Data.Typeable(Typeable)

data QTree a = Internal (QTree a) (QTree a) (QTree a) (QTree a)
             | Leaf a
             deriving (Data,Typeable -- for uniplate
                       , Eq, Show)
-- not tested:
fix :: (Data a, Eq a) => QTree a -> QTree a
fix t = case map fix $ children t of
  lw@(Leaf w):xyz
    | all (lw ==) xyz -> lw
  _                   -> t
```

These simple generics plus our ability to combine predicates with pattern matching in a `case` fix what *actually* bothered me about both versions which were the duplicated identical branches.